# best way to secure metal strip between tiles and wooden floor?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, metal

We have a metal strip between our bathroom and hallway, which have tiles & wooden flooring. It keeps dislocating from where it is supposed to fit. What's the best way to secure it? Please see the photo attached, and if possible use UK DIY terms & links! Thanks[image: ![metal strip]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auNf8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a snap in style once they pull out a few times the Chanel may need to be squeezed together if the raised section on the back of the trim is still in tact. If the raised section has broken off 3 small flat head screws can be added by predrilling and counter sinking the holes (predrill in place to punch a hole in the channel ). This would be how I would repair it to stay in place.